# New design launched

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see the new design just went live, which means this site has been officially launched! Congratulations! Thank you for being an awesome community!

If you're still seeing the old favicons, please load the following urls and do a hard browser refresh.

[Main site favicon](http://sstatic.net/christianity/img/favicon.ico)

[Meta site favicon](http://sstatic.net/christianitymeta/img/favicon.ico)

I've also themed the [twitter](https://twitter.com/stackchristian) account and email newsletter template for this site. When our dev Ben gets back from vacation in a few days, we'll be revamping the chatroom theme as well.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post here on Meta and tag it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

For the Meta theme, I changed the footer image to a sandy beach theme. I think it works well with the over all nature look. Also it reminds me of the [Footprints in the Sand](http://llerrah.com/footprints.htm) poem.

Thank you for your design feedback. In my experience it takes a bit to get used to the new design. If the community feels strongly about certain design changes, I'll tweak them post launch.

Again, congratulations!

Comment: Nice work, @Jin! Thank you for all you do!

Comment: I really love this design.

Comment: Great design. Absolutely love it.

Comment: Wow, this design is fantastic!... Great going! :)

Comment: The ichthus-badge thing was such a great idea...love it!